# Automatically update a greasemonkey script under development

Tags: firefox, greasemonkey, userscripts

I am a big fan of greasemonkey but there is one thing I don't like - every time when I updated a script, I need to drag the script from explorer to a browser window, wait a few seconds and click "install", then refresh the target page to see the effect.

A recent Firefox upgrade just added one more click to the whole process. It's probably acceptable for an end user but it's truly just a pain when the script is under active development - where it is frequently updated. Ideally, I am looking for a console interface that can directly "push" the updated script into Firefox without (or minimum for security reason) any delay or click.

**UPDATE**

I just tried "edit this user script" as ov1d1u suggested. There are two problems: 1) the internal editor is not as good as my preference; 2) it works in a secret folder that is hard to use source control. However, since it revealed a secret folder, I tried to update the file directly in this folder and it worked! I just created one batch file with the following content:

```
xcopy /d my.user.js "...\AppData\Roaming\...\gm_scripts\...\"
```

This is by far a good enough solution to what I wanted.

Comment: If you go to `User Scripts` on `about:addons`, press the `Preferences` button near your script and then press `Edit this User Script` aren't the modifications applied automatically from that editor?

Comment: > "the internal editor is not as good as my preference" I think it's actually the default editor. So if you configured your best editor as default, it will be used to open the user script.

Comment: You should post your edit as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As janot suggested, I am posting what worked for me as an answer here.

**The following is from my original question update:**

I just tried "edit this user script" as ov1d1u suggested. There are two problems: 1) the internal editor is not as good as my preference; 2) it works in a secret folder that is hard to use source control. However, since it revealed a secret folder, I tried to update the file directly in this folder and it worked! I just created one batch file with the following content:

```
xcopy /d my.user.js "...\AppData\Roaming\...\gm_scripts\...\"
```

This is by far a good enough solution to what I wanted.

**Feb 2016 Update**

It has been two years since this question was asked. Now I switched to Chrome+Tampermonkey. Tampermonkey allows updating a script locally by specifying a updateURL in the script. In this way, I just setup a simple HTTP server locally and updating a script is two-click from inside of Chrome. This is probably not something new but I just want to mention it here.